# Sqlite giving same output and not considering where clause order

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I want to get the entry from database using sqlite3 using sqlite_prepare_v2() in c interface and used to get the out put not in the expected order.
want to get the entry in the exact order in which size is given in the where clause but behavior is as below:

```
sqlite> select id,size from audio where size in (9,16,8);
3|9
4|8
5|16

sqlite> 
sqlite> select id,size from audio where size in (8,9,16);
3|9
4|8
5|16

sqlite> 
sqlite> select id,size from audio where size in (16,8,9);
3|9
4|8
5|16
```

For the first query, I am expecting the ouput to be in other order of size inside the where clause, but is seems sqlite is by default always giving the output in the order of the id. here id is the primary key field. Is sqlite using any default indexing on primary key field making this to happen? or is there a way to get the output from the sqlite as it is given in the where clause? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the `in()` clause is irrelevant to the order of the `select` results.

In order to get the `select` results in the desired order, you must either add an explicit `order by` clause that fits your need, such as `order by size` in the second case, or you must issue 3 separate `select` statements in the desired order.

Comment: Actually if i use "order by size" it will be ascending order of the size. wanted it to be in the order how it is given in the where in clause. so this is not possible? in the c program we have to do sqlite3_prepare_v2() multiple time if i start fetching the entry one by one. and this will be a overhead.